# Integral of arctan of two functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm dealing with an integral of the form
$$
I = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f_1 \, \text{d}f_2 \, - f_2 \, \text{d}f_1}{f_1^2+f_2^2}
$$
where $f_1:=f_1(x)$ and $f_2:=f_2(x)$ and there are no failures of continuity or differentiability of the individual functions in $[x_1,x_2]$ though it may be that $f_2(x)=0$ for some values of $x$.

I have seen the above expressed as
$$ 
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f_1 \, \text{d}f_2 \, - f_2 \, \text{d}f_1}{f_1^2+f_2^2} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \text{d} \arctan \left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right),
$$
which I think I can demonstrate to be valid.

If indeed it is valid, I would understand the solution then to be given by
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \text{d} \arctan \left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right) = \left[ \arctan\left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right) \right]_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2} = \arctan \left\{\frac{f_1(x_2)}{f_2(x_2)}\ \right\} - \arctan \left\{\frac{f_1(x_1)}{f_2(x_1)}\ \right\}.
$$
However, $\arctan()$ is taken to have bounds $\left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, +\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$, whereas if I evaluate the original integral numerically, these bounds are clearly not observed.  And I know the numerical solution to the original integral is correct.

What are the deficiencies here?  I am aware that the integral of $\arctan\left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right)$ may be subject to a failure of Fubini's Theorem but I'm not sure whether that applies here.

Look forward to your valuable comments, thank you.

Comment: Your formula is only valid on intervals on which $f_2$ has no zeros.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR.  By that do you mean the formula in which $I$ is transformed to $\int d \arctan(f_1/f_2)$?  If so, could you help me understand where in the transformation it fails?

Comment: $\arctan(f_1/f_2)$ is *not defined* at points where $f_2(x) = 0$.

Comment: @MartinR  Aha, so would you agree therefore my mistake is in the step where I apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} d \arctan(f_1/f_2) = \left[\arctan(f_1/f_2)\right]_{x_1}^{x_2}$ which does not hold because of discontinuity at all points for which f_2=0.